# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin="*" to the response header in WSO2 DSS

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I made a data service with WSO2 DSS. It can handle rest-like queries like get services/person/get_name?id=1000 and send response by http in json format. I would like to add a parameter to http header of response - Access-Control-Allow-Origin"="*" (to do cross domain scripting with jquery ajax). Is there a way to add a parameter? Thank You!

Comment: You might need to front DSS with a ESB REST API, and add the said header in the outSequence of the ESB rest api.

Comment: thank you for your comment..can we do without ESB ??

Comment: You can take the WSO2 ESB and install DSS features on it.

Comment: I want to fix this cross-domain issue without using WSO2 ESB, Is there any option for that ??

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 DSS does not have the implementation for support the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

You have 3 alternatives to achieve this

1. Write your own custom axis2 handler
2. Use ESB and expose your REST Service
3. Use API manger and expose your REST Service.

Comment: Is there any doc or blog regarding your first option (custom axis2 handler)?